# Unable to display Data using recordViewForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to display list of contacts based on the accountId.In the component's helper,I am able to get the accountId in debug logs but when I use lightning:recordViewForm inside an aura:iteration tag then it doesn't show error and does not display any records either. Please let me know the issue. Here's the code.

**Server-Side Controller**

```
public static List<Contact> getContacts(List<ID> accountIDs){
        return [select Id,FirstName,LastName from contact
                where AccountId in : accountIDs];
}
```

**Component**:

```
 <aura:component implements=flexipage:availableForRecordHome,
                       force:hasRecordId,
                       controller="MyContactController">
   <aura:attribute name="contactList" type="List"
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.FetchContactList}"/>
   <aura:if isTrue="{! not( empty( v.recordId))}">
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactList}" var="con">
      <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!con.Id}" objectApiName="contact">
        <lightning:outputField fieldName="{FirstName}" />
          <lightning:outputField fieldName="{LastName}" />
```

**Client-Side Controller:**

```
FetchContacts : function(component,event,helper) {
 var action = component.get("c.getContacts");
 var accId=component.get('v.recordId');
 action.setParams({"accountIDs" : accId});
  action.setCallback(this,function(response)
    {
        var state=response.getState();           
        if (state === "SUCCESS")
        {
            var conList=response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.contactList",conList);
        }
       });
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
 })
```

Comment: Post the lightning markup as well

Comment: <aura:component implements=flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,
                      controller="MyContactController"
        <aura:attribute name="contactList"  type="List"
          <aura:handler name="init"  value="{!this}"  action="{!c.FetchContactList}"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactList}" var="con">
     <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!con.Id}" objectApiName="contact">
   <lightning:outputField fieldName="{!con.FirstName}"/>

Comment: ({FetchContactList : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.FetchContacts(component,event,helper);}}
({
 FetchContacts : function(component,event,helper) {
          var action = component.get("c.getContacts");
         var accId=component.get('v.recordId');
        action.setParams({ "accountIDs" : accId });
         action.setCallback(this,function(response)
        { var state=response.getState();           
            if (state === "SUCCESS")
            {  var conList=response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.contactList",conList);}

Comment: MyContactController@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(List<ID> accountIDs){
        return [select Id,FirstName,LastName,Phone,Email
                from contact
                where AccountId in : accountIDs]; }

Comment: <aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:MyContactController recordId="0017F00000cBFdUQAW"/> 
</aura:application>

Answer (score 2):

Few observations about your code.

1. You are passing single accountId to your apex class, but collecting it in a List. So correction is needed in your apex class.
2. RecordId of an account is not flowing from an aura:application to aura:component. *force:hasRecordId* could have worked only if you are directly calling your lightning component from an lightning action.
   So you need to have an attribute on your *aura:component* to capture recordId.
3. In *lightning:outputField* for fieldName attribute you are using {!con.FirstName} which is incorrect. fieldName should be the api name of the field, in this case it's "FirstName"

Final code:

Apex Class Method:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Contact> getContacts(Id accountIDs) {
    return [Select Id, FirstName FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accountIDs];
}
```

Lightning Component Code:

```
<aura:attribute name="contactList" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" /> <!-- added line -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.FetchContactList}"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.contactList}" var="con"> 
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!con.Id}" objectApiName="Contact"> 
        <lightning:outputField fieldName="FirstName"/> 
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
</aura:iteration>
```

Component Helper Code:

```
FetchContacts : function(component,event,helper) { 
    var action = component.get("c.getContacts"); 
    var accId = component.get('v.recordId'); 
    action.setParams({ "accountIDs" : accId }); 
    action.setCallback(this,function(response) { 
        var state=response.getState(); 
        if (state === "SUCCESS") { 
            var conList = response.getReturnValue(); 
            component.set("v.contactList",conList);
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Comment: I made the changes as u showed.But I don't see any records even in account detail page. I replaced lightning:outputField with datatable(tr & td tags) and in apex method I passed List<ID> in parameter . This works and it shows records in account detail page. I request u to tell me if further changes are required  if I use lightning:output..